# How to convert query select json where json mysql to php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, select

> data on tblusers.xdata

```
{"name":"a","jabatan":"1","pic":"a.jpg"},
{"name":"b","jabatan":"2","pic":"b.jpg"},
{"name":"c","jabatan":"3","pic":"c.jpg"},
{"name":"d","jabatan":"4","pic":"d.jpg"}


query json in mysql success
```

> SELECT xdata->'$.name', xdata->'$.jabatan', xdata->'$.pic'
>       FROM tblusers
>       WHERE xdata->'$.jabatan' = '3' OR xdata->'$.jabatan' = '2'
>
> but how to convert query json in codeigniter where json condition

```
reff:: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-query-a-json-column-in-mysql/
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a query from your custom sql statements, you could use codeigniter db `query()` method :

```php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT xdata->'$.name', xdata->'$.jabatan', xdata->'$.pic' FROM tblusers WHERE xdata->'$.jabatan' = '3' OR xdata->'$.jabatan' = '2'");

var_dump($query->result_array());
```

Comment: this output array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'xdata->'$.name'' => string '"b"' (length=18)
      'xdata->'$.jabatan'' => string '"3"' (length=3)
      'xdata->'$.pic'' => string '"b.jpg"' (length=38)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'xdata->'$.name'' => string '"c"' (length=9)
      'xdata->'$.jabatan'' => string '"2"' (length=3)
      xdata->'$.pic'' => string '""' (length=2) ** how to call xdata->to html **

Comment: if i call on html <h3 class="mt-3 text-green h4"><?= $xdata['jabatan']  ?> blabla</h3>
            <img src="<?= xdata->'$.pic' ?>" class="user-image" alt="<?=  xdata->'$.name' ?>"/>
            <span class="hidden-xs"><?=  xdata->'$.name' ?></span> so error

Comment: model CI 
public function get_select_json() { 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT xdata->'$.name', xdata->'$.jabatan', xdata->'$.avatar' FROM tblusers WHERE xdata->'$.jabatan' = '2' OR xdata->'$.jabatan' = '3'");

 var_dump($query->result_array());
 }

Controller CI
$query = $this ->user ->get_select_json();
    $n='';
    $j='';
    $a='';
  //foreach ($query as $row){
  foreach($query as $row){
             
   print $n=$row->name;
   print $j=$row->jabatan;
   print $a=$row->pic;
   
  }

View Ci

how to call this